# How to connect to hidden wireless network (no SSID) with windows NETSH command?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless, netsh

i want to connect to hidden wireless network (no SSID) with NETSH command.

my access point has SSID but i invisible it for security reasons.

is there a way to connect with simple commands and no user interface???

best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some days i founded a solution that is work well.

**1: create a .xml file for example "c:\NOSSID.XML" and save below code into it:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
    <name>SampleWPA2PSK</name>
    <SSIDConfig>
        <SSID>
            <name>D.Mainoffice.Access</name>
        </SSID>
    </SSIDConfig>
    <connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
    <connectionMode>auto</connectionMode>
    <autoSwitch>true</autoSwitch>
    <MSM>
        <security>
            <authEncryption>
                <authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication>
                <encryption>AES</encryption>
                <useOneX>false</useOneX>
            </authEncryption>  
   <sharedKey>
    <keyType>passPhrase</keyType>
    <protected>false</protected>
    <keyMaterial>**** password ****</keyMaterial>
   </sharedKey>
        </security>
    </MSM>
</WLANProfile>
```

**2: run netsh command:**

```
Netsh wlan add profile filename="c:\noSSID.xml"
```

you could change your own hidden SSID in `<name>` tag and password in `<keymaterial>` tag !!!

that's so easy and i hope be useful for others.